# ExtJs grid column headers missing

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I've got a simple ExtJS grid, and can't seem to get the column headers to show up. the data shows up in the rows just fine, and the entire dataset fits in the assigned space with room to spare. The grid is rendered into a div that itself is the source of a modal dialog. What am I missing?

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapperdiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Dialog code:

```
$('#wrapperdiv').dialog({
   title: 'title',
   resizable: false,
   modal: true,
   width: 700,
   height: 300,
   buttons: {
      Close: function () {
         $(this).dialog('close');
      }
   }
});
```

Grid code:

```
var panel = Ext.create(
   'Ext.grid.Panel',
   {
      border: true,
      autoScroll: true,
      width: 680,
      height: 200,
      layout: 'fit',
      id: 'theGrid',
      renderTo: 'wrapperdiv',
      columns:
      [
         { text: 'Col1', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'col1', hideable: false, sortable: true },
         { text: 'Col2', width: 120, align: 'center', dataIndex: 'col2', hideable: false, sortable: false },
         { text: 'Col3', width: 70, align: 'center', dataIndex: 'col3', hideable: false, sortable: false },
         { text: 'Col4', width: 100, align: 'center', dataIndex: 'col4', hideable: false, sortable: false }
      ],
      store: dataStore
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine without any issue.

Check the fiddle link here -

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nGdM3/2/
```

I would like to give one suggestion though - instead of using jquery dialog box combined with Extjs Grid Panel, you can use `extjs window`.

Comment: Thanks... there's a ton of other extjs stuff on that page that I didn't write; must be conflicting somehow.